# integrate gapi in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, google-analytics

I would like to integrate gapi in my codeigniter site. So I have been downloading the gapi class and included between my other library files. Than in my controller I'm initialising the library and with the following line I'm trying to pass to the constructor the google analytics details

```
$this->load->library( 'gapi', array( 'email' => "email",'password' => "pass" ));
```

but unfortunately doesn't really happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the file gapi.class.php to gapi.php

Rename the class form “gapi” to “Gapi”

Replace:

```
public function __construct($email, $password, $token=null)
{
    if($token !== null)
    {
        $this->auth_token = $token;
    }
    else 
    {
        $this->authenticateUser($email,$password);
    }
} 
public function __construct($params)
{
    $email = (isset($params['email']))?$params['email']:NULL;
    $password = (isset($params['password']))?$params['password']:NULL;
    $token = (isset($params['token']))?$params['token']:NULL;

    if($token !== null)
    {
        $this->auth_token = $token;
    }
    else 
    {
        $this->authenticateUser($email,$password);
    }
}
```